# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I use the below mentioned query to Flatten an ObservableCollection:

```
using(RateDifferenceDBEntities db = new RateDifferenceDBEntities())
{
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(db.Items);


    Orders = new ObservableCollection<ClaimDTO>(from order in db.Orders
                                                from orderItemDetail in order.OrderItemDetails
                                                from dispatch in order.Dispatches
                                                from dispatchItemDetail in dispatch.DispatchItemDetails
                                                where ((orderItemDetail.ItemId == dispatchItemDetail.ItemId && dispatchItemDetail.Rate > orderItemDetail.Rate)
                                                        && (dispatch.DateOfDispatch >= StartDate && dispatch.DateOfDispatch <= EndDate))
                                                select new ClaimDTO
                                                {
                                                    SalesOrderId = order.SalesOrderId,
                                                    DateOfOrder = order.DateOfOrder,
                                                    PartyName = order.Party.PartyName,
                     ------------>                  OrderItemName = Items.Where(x => x.ItemId == orderItemDetail.ItemId).FirstOrDefault().ItemName,
                                                    OrderQuantity = orderItemDetail.Quantity,
                                                    OrderRate = orderItemDetail.Rate,
                                                    OrderAmount = orderItemDetail.Amount,
                                                    SalesInvoiceId = dispatch.SalesInvoiceId,
                                                    DateOfDispatch = dispatch.DateOfDispatch,
                     ------------>                  DispatchItemName = Items.Where(x => x.ItemId == dispatchItemDetail.ItemId).FirstOrDefault().ItemName,
                                                    DispatchQuantity = dispatchItemDetail.Quantity,
                                                    DispatchRate = dispatchItemDetail.Rate,
                                                    DispatchAmount = dispatchItemDetail.Amount
                                                });

    return Orders;
}
```

Can you see two dotted arrows in above code??

I geet an error there:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Data.Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Here is the Heirarchical collection that I use to build the above mentioned query:

```
Order //Collection
 |-OrderId
 |-DateOfOrder
 |-PartyName
 |-OrderDetails //Collection
 |    |-ItemName
 |    |-Quantity
 |    |-Rate
 |    |-Amount
 |-Dispatch //Collection
 |    |-InvoiceNo
 |    |-DateOfDispatch
 |    |-DispatchDetails //Collection
 |    |    |-ItemName
 |    |    |-Quantity
 |    |    |-Rate
 |    |    |-Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the 2 dotted lines where you are getting errors, you are trying to join a local dataset (items) with a database query (non-materialized) dataset.

```
Items.Where(x => x.ItemId == orderItemDetail.ItemId).FirstOrDefault().ItemName,
```

This is not allowed by EF or LINQ2SQL.

Either you need to

- materialize both datasets and then run predicates on them locally in-memory, or
- have both datasets as IQueryable or
- use something like [PredicateBuilder from LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build the predicate for the IQueryable using the local dataset.

i think the easiest thing to do would be not use the Observale Items variable in the query and use db.Items.

```
Orders = new ObservableCollection<ClaimDTO>(from order in db.Orders
                                            from goodItems in db.Items
                                            from orderItemDetail in order.OrderItemDetails
                                            from dispatch in order.Dispatches
                                            from dispatchItemDetail in dispatch.DispatchItemDetails
                                            where ((orderItemDetail.ItemId == dispatchItemDetail.ItemId && dispatchItemDetail.Rate > orderItemDetail.Rate)
                                                    && (dispatch.DateOfDispatch >= StartDate && dispatch.DateOfDispatch <= EndDate))
                                            select new ClaimDTO
                                            {
                                                SalesOrderId = order.SalesOrderId,
                                                DateOfOrder = order.DateOfOrder,
                                                PartyName = order.Party.PartyName,
                 ------------>                  OrderItemName = goodItems.Where(x => x.ItemId == orderItemDetail.ItemId).FirstOrDefault().ItemName,
                                                OrderQuantity = orderItemDetail.Quantity,
                                                OrderRate = orderItemDetail.Rate,
                                                OrderAmount = orderItemDetail.Amount,
                                                SalesInvoiceId = dispatch.SalesInvoiceId,
                                                DateOfDispatch = dispatch.DateOfDispatch,
                 ------------>                  DispatchItemName = goodItems.Where(x => x.ItemId == dispatchItemDetail.ItemId).FirstOrDefault().ItemName,
                                                DispatchQuantity = dispatchItemDetail.Quantity,
                                                DispatchRate = dispatchItemDetail.Rate,
                                                DispatchAmount = dispatchItemDetail.Amount
                                            });

return Orders;
```

Comment: In my Heirarchical collection as shown in the question, I already have OrderItemName and DispatchItemName. How can I get that directly from heirarchical collection instead of fetching data from database?

Comment: Materialized and not materialized values are not the problem here - though you would surpass these errors by materializing the query results. NONE of these entries are materialized at query generation time, EF just has to create an appropriate query for it. The problem is that you are actually comparing complex data types (Items) with each other, and EF has no idea how to translate this to SQL. You can nest your entries like that, however you should compare the FK's or PK's of entries in your queries, not your entries altogether.